# iOS: Best practice for placing the close brace

Tags: c

I really like to know, which is the best coding practice to have close brace (}) in Objective C based enterprise project.
I would like to define the method and condition statements like below. Please advise, which is the best coding practice in Objective C and why. I have not seen about this in Apple's coding standard document though.

Which is correct, Close brace should be same line or below?

I.

```
-(void) method {
       .... 
}

(or) 

-(void) method 
{
      .... 
}
```

II.

```
-(void) method {
          if ( ... ) {
                .....
          }
          else {
                .....
          }
    }

    (or) 

    -(void) method 
    {
          if ( ... ) 
          {
                .....
          }
          else 
          {
                .....
          }
    }
```

Comment: How could one be "better practice" than the other? It's just preference. Choose one and stick with it.

Comment: Any of those are fine.  Personally, I use a bit of a mix of the styles you have listed, for short methods and code blocks I have the opening brace in line and for larger ones I put it on a new line.

Comment: Don't forget `} else {`, where both braces are on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any standards on code formatting. It's just preferential. Although I tend to do whatever I can to reduce whitespace.

For example:

```
-(void)myMethod{
    [self doSomething];
}
```

Comment: In the interest of discussion, why is it more readable to have the brace brackets NOT line up? To me, it'd be easier to read if the code block beginning/end were clearly visible and lined up. As you said though, it is preference. I'm just curious.

Comment: @rar - I guess when I'm looking at code, my eyes recognize whitespace as space between methods. So I don't want my methods to have the whitespace added when a '{' character is on its own line. And again, that's just my preference.

Answer (score 4):

This is down to *personal preference*. There is no "best practice" on this. Choose the one you like and use it. You can even mix and match if you like.

*In the end it is YOUR code. You decide how you want to lay it out.*

Comment: Until another programmer comes along and has to work with *YOUR* code.

Answer (score 1):

I like the second approach because it gives more visibility of the code although I'm not aware of any official code convention for objective-c. I would suggest u to keep the convention that already exists in your project or choose one you like if it is a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean open brace?

Anyway, I've always felt that the starting brace bracket of a function/method should be on its own line (rather than on the same line as the function name/parameters) so that you can line them up more easily. It's visually much easier to line up the brace brackets and see where your code blocks start/end when you line them up.

That being said, Bo A's answer is correct in that it's entirely up to you. There is no "best practice" .